# Although I've used Rnd Function, it doesn't TRULY give random numbers, how can I modify my existing code to gain randomly, distinct values?

Tags: vb.net, random

```
Sub Monte_Carlo_Integration_Of_A_Function()
    Dim x As Double, y As Double, num As Integer
    Randomize()
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("Monte Carlo Integration")
    Console.WriteLine("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
    Console.WriteLine("Please Enter A Number?")
    num = Console.ReadLine()
    x = Rnd()
    y = Rnd()
    For i = 1 To num
        Console.WriteLine(x)
        Console.WriteLine(y)
        Console.WriteLine()
    Next
```

How do I modify this code to gain distinct, random numbers

Comment: If by "distinct", you mean you don't want to randomly select the same number more than once, you need to be aware that truly random numbers can repeat. If what you want to do is randomly select numbers without duplication, I suggest putting all the allowable numbers in a list. You can randomly select a number from the list and then remove that number, leaving a smaller list for the next random selection.

Comment: Basically, within the for loop, I want x and y to display different random numbers, instead of the same number through each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the next set of random numbers before entering the `For` loop, like this:

```
x = Rnd()  ' Assign next random number to x
y = Rnd()  ' Assign next random number to y
For i = 1 To num
    Console.WriteLine(x)  ' Display the value of x
    Console.WriteLine(y)  ' Display the value of y
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

You need to get the next set of next random numbers inside the `For` loop so that a new set of random numbers is generated for each iteration of the loop:

```
For i = 1 To num
    x = Rnd()  ' Assign next random number to x
    y = Rnd()  ' Assign next random number to y
    Console.WriteLine(x)  ' Display the value of x
    Console.WriteLine(y)  ' Display the value of y
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

However, `Randomize` and `Rnd` are old VB6-style commands which are mostly only still available in VB.NET for backwards compatibility.  In new VB.NET development, it is recommended that you use the `Random` class, like this:

```
Dim r As New Random()
For i = 1 To num
    x = r.NextDouble()
    y = r.NextDouble()
    Console.WriteLine(x)
    Console.WriteLine(y)
    Console.WriteLine()
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is the solution... god you have no idea how long I've been trying to figure this out